# How to store apk to sdcard when installing into device

Tags: android, manifest, device, sd-card

How to install the application on the device's external storage.what parameters we need write in manifest file in android.

Comment: Check this out: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
 android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

in your manifest as

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation="preferExternal" 
>
```

If you declare "**preferExternal**", you request that your application be installed on the external storage, but the system does not guarantee that your application will be installed on the external storage. If the external storage is full, the system will install it on the internal storage.

For More info see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

Answer (score 0):

Add installLocatiion attribute in your application manifest file.

android:installLocation="preferExternal"

Comment: can you give some exaplanations